# MySQL 4 Table Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've been trying to get the proper data for this 4-table join for awhile and I can't seem to pin it down.  I'm trying to grab a list of ids from `songs` based on who I am following in `follows`, and show the song id if my followers are the `creator` of the track or just reshared it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT songs.id
FROM songs
LEFT JOIN follows ON follows.follower = 6
LEFT JOIN tracks ON tracks.creator = follows.following
LEFT JOIN reshares ON reshares.resharer = follows.following
WHERE
songs.id = tracks.containing_song
OR
songs.id = reshares.song
ORDER BY songs.last_updated DESC LIMIT 1
```

I'm not quite sure what's wrong, but my knowledge is very limited when it comes to database joins.

Comment: Why do you join on `follows.follower = 6` ? Please post the expected result, the current result, and the datas.

Comment: And the tables schemas if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need is a union of two sets:

- songs created by people user with id=6 follows
- songs reshared by people user with id=6 follows

Since you haven't provided table schemas I'm using names you provided in the query.

```
( SELECT DISTINCT s.id, s.last_updated
  FROM follows f
  JOIN tracks t ON t.creator = f.following
  JOIN songs s ON t.containing_song = s.id
  WHERE f.follower = 6 )
UNION
( SELECT DISTINCT s.id, s.last_updated
  FROM follows f
  JOIN reshares r ON r.resharer = f.following
  JOIN songs s ON r.song = s.id
  WHERE f.follower = 6 )
ORDER BY last_updated DESC
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I think it works!  I've never used UNION before, so this is interesting.